# Syntax issue or using an indirect reference in bash to name an array

Tags: arrays, bash, reference

Obviously this is incorrect, which is what brings me here.  Please help to show me the light.

I am iterating through a file.  I am taking some fields and assigning them to indices of an array.  For each pass of the loop, i want to change the name of the array.  For example, in the first pass of the loop, i want to assign indices to array1, second pass assign indices to array2, and so forth until i reach the amount of lines in file, or total=$(wc -l < file)

```
#!/bin/bash
total=$(wc -l < file)
counter=0
  while [ $counter -ne $total ]
    do
      (( counter = counter + 1 ))
        name=array$counter
        name[0]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f1)
        name[1]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f2)
        name[2]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f3)
        name[4]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f6)
        echo $counter ${name[4]}
    done
read -p "enter a number: " number
```

I hope this makes sense.  it should be something fairly simple to do, i think i just have a syntax issue.  From what i can find in research i need to use an indirect reference.

i have a file that will have anywhere from 1-50 lines, possibly more. each line will be 6 fields separated by a | symbol. i want to list the 6th column out with $counter in front (this will act as a menu). the user will then choose a number (im using `read -p "enter a number: " number` . Then a command will execute using some variables ( -f1 and -f2 ) for the appropriate array

An example of my input file:

```
abcdefghijklm|10|-45|476|85f|someString1
jydbefgsdffty|01|-95|423|73c|someString2
jgrtefghijksd|31|-75|920|75a|someString3
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
1 someString1
2 someString2
3 someString3

enter a number:
```

i came up with another approach.  Since i dont need all the data to be stored as variables (i am using a menu to select one particular line and use only its data), then i list all lines/fields i want with cat command piped to sed and cut.  then i make a selection, and only add the selected lines/fields to variable.   problem solved.  thanks everyone.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed us a sample of your file and the corresponding output. I don't understand what you're trying to do with an array.

Comment: i have a file that will have anywhere from 1-50 lines, possibly more. each line will be 6 fields separated by a | symbol.  i want to list the 6th column out with $counter in front (this will act as a menu).  the user will then choose a number (im using `read -p "enter a number: "  number` .  Then a command will execute using some variables ( -f1 and -f2 ) for the appropriate array

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add this information? Ideally with a concrete example of input and output.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to iterate through a file is to use a `while` loop that calls `read`, which can split the line for you.

```
counter=0
while IFS="|" read -ra arr; do
    printf '%s %s\n' "$counter" "${arr[5]}"
    counter=$((counter + 1))
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you *came up with another approach*, I'll address your original problem.

> … in the first pass of the loop, i want to assign indices to array1, second pass assign indices to array2, and so forth …
>
> From what i can find in research i need to use an indirect reference.

Well, newer versions of bash have an option to declare a variable with the [*nameref*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) attribute; with this, you'd just have to change `name=array$counter` to `declare -n name=array$counter`, and your script would work as desired.

Older versions of bash (which would respond to the above with `declare: -n: invalid option`) also have a special indirection syntax, but not working with arrays. With such a version, we'd have to resort to `eval` and appropriate use of `\` to get a certain evaluation order:

```
        name=array$counter
        eval $name[0]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f1)
        eval $name[1]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f2)
        eval $name[2]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f3)
        eval $name[4]=$(cat file | sed "${counter}q;d" | cut -d '|' -f6)
        eval echo $counter \${$name[4]}
```

The `\` in that last line has the effect that first `$name` is expanded, e. g. to `array1`, and only after that `${array1[4]}` is `eval`uated.